# csv live data highchart

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

My data won't display proper.
I have this kind of data: "1456135353.000000|5424492576222277|8156610153681827"

"1456135353" is for the time.

"5424492576222277" is for the first X

"8156610153681827" is for the second X

This is my code:

```
    var chart

/**
 * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout
 * to request again
 */
function requestData () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'api/chart',
          dataType: 'text',
        success: function (point) {
            var series = chart.series[0].push
                                                 // longer than 20
            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true)
            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000)
        },
        cache: false
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'XSnews Graph'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#197F07',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'GB',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Time',
            data: []
        }]
    })
})
```

I am not familiar with Highcharts so I have no clue what I am doing wrong. 
Do I need to parse it?

Comment: Have a look on the documentation http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module

Comment: I am unclear what the desired result is. is this meant to be two series, each with a *y* value at the same time stamp (*x* value)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse  your data first, before adding a point. Something like this:

```
success: function (point) {
    var options = point.split("|"),
        x = parseFloat(options[0]) * 1000,
        y_1 = parseFloat(options[1]),
        y_2 = parseFloat(options[2]);

    chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y_1], true);
    setTimeout(requestData, 1000)'
}
```